# Polygonize a vertical plane defined by a MultiLineString Z in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, 3d, polygonize, vertical

I have to [polygonize](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Polygonize.html) a vertical plane defined by a `MultiLineString Z`:

```sql
SELECT ST_AsText((ST_Dump(ST_Polygonize(ST_GeomFromText(
    'MULTILINESTRING Z ((
        0 0 3,
        1 1 3,
        2 2 0,
        1 1 0,
        0 0 3
    ))', 3857
)))).geom);
 st_astext 
-----------
(0 rows)
```

But as you can see, the result is empty.

Shifting one coordinate a little gives a correct result:

```sql
SELECT ST_AsText((ST_Dump(ST_Polygonize(ST_GeomFromText(
    'MULTILINESTRING Z ((
        0 0 3,
        1 1 3,
        2 2 0,
        1 1.001 0,
        0 0 3
    ))', 3857
)))).geom);
 geom 
                   st_astext                   
-----------------------------------------------
 POLYGON Z ((0 0 3,1 1.001 0,2 2 0,1 1 3,0 0 3))
(1 row)
```

Is there a way to get this in the first case:

```sql
SELECT ST_AsText((ST_Dump(ST_Polygonize(ST_GeomFromText(
    'MULTILINESTRING Z ((
        0 0 3,
        1 1 3,
        2 2 0,
        1 1 0,
        0 0 3
    ))', 3857
)))).geom);
 geom 
                   st_astext                   
-----------------------------------------------
 POLYGON Z ((0 0 3,1 1 0,2 2 0,1 1 3,0 0 3))
(1 row)
```

or something equivalent?

---

Fun fact:

```sql
SELECT ST_IsValid(ST_GeomFromText(
    'MULTILINESTRING Z ((
        0 0 3,
        1 1 3,
        2 2 0,
        1 1 0,
        0 0 3
    ))', 3857
));
 st_isvalid 
------------
 t
(1 row)
```

But obviously not on the equivalent Polygon Z: `NOTICE:  Ring Self-intersection at or near point 1 1`.

---

As a background, at the end of the process, I need to triangulate that plane into an OBJ or PLY file.

Comment: The GEOS library does not handle 3D. It can handle 2.5D, so 2D geometries with height but height is more like an attribute or measure then. Your vertical polygon makes a line when projected on a horizontal plane and therefore it is not valid for GEOS.

Comment: I am not sure if SFCGAL backend would help. At least it should show an area for the vertical polygon https://postgis.net/docs/ST_3DArea.html.

Comment: Indeed, but the `MULTILINESTRING Z` geometry must be converted (how?) into a `POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z` before. Then `ST_3DArea` returns `4.242640687119286`. Otherwise it returns a `parse error - invalid geometry`.